# C Traverse Directory and Print Entries in Pairs

Tags: c, directory

Suppose I have the following abstraction of code:

```
  DIR *d;
  struct dirent *sd; 
  d = opendir("SOME DIRECTORY");
  // handle errors 
  sd = readdir(d);
  while(sd != NULL){
    printf("(%s, %s)\n", sd->d_name, sd->the_next_d_name);
    sd = readdir(d);
  }
  closedir(dir);
```

I'm a bit new to c and going into detail with `man` pages. I just wanted to get an idea of how I'm to get access to two entries of the directory while in the loop body. The code uses some pseudo names to get the idea across. Also, if there are an odd number of entries, I would like the last pair to have an entry paired with `NULL`

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Unclear !Be more specific . Write your expected output in question and also mention what you want to do

Comment: If I have the contents 'a.txt', 'b.txt', and 'c.txt' in my directory, I want the code to print '(a.txt, b.txt)\n(c.txt, NULL)'

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that the [`readdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html) function doesn't preserve previously returned values when it is called a second time:

> The application shall not modify the structure to which the return value of `readdir()` points, nor any storage areas pointed to by pointers within the structure. The returned pointer, and pointers within the structure, might be invalidated or the structure or the storage areas might be overwritten by a subsequent call to `readdir()` on the same directory stream. They shall not be affected by a call to `readdir()` on a different directory stream.

So, you have to make a copy of the name for the first of each pair of entries.  Presumably, you have [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) available, so this is minimally painful.  (If perchance you do not have `strdup()`, it is very easy to write your own version — 7 lines, including lines with only braces on them.)

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stderr.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc > 2)
        err_usage("[directory]");
    char *dir = ".";
    if (argc == 2)
        dir = argv[1];
    DIR *dp = opendir(dir);
    if (dp == NULL)
        err_syserr("failed to open directory '%s': ", dir);
    char *name_0 = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    struct dirent *name;
    while ((name = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        if (++counter % 2 == 1)
        {
            if ((name_0 = strdup(name->d_name)) == NULL)
                err_syserr("failed to duplicate name '%s': ", name->d_name);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("(%s, %s)\n", name_0, name->d_name);
            free(name_0);
            name_0 = NULL;
        }
    }
    if (counter % 2 == 1)
        printf("(%s, %s)\n", name_0, "NULL");
    free(name_0);
    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
```

(The functions declared in `stderr.h` all start `err_` and greatly simplify error reporting.  You can find their code on GitHub at https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq.)